# Oozie workflow giving error on Hive job when underlying job completes successfully

Tags: debugging, hadoop, hive, runtime-error, oozie

Part of self-learning I am exploring `Oozie`, and I am practicing on [Hortonworks Sandbox VM](http://hortonworks.com/products/sandbox/). The problem is that `Oozie` workflow is getting error and getting killed as a result when underlying job given by the link in Oozie UI shows success.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749999/oozie-workflow-hive-table-not-found-but-it-does-exist) question and have included

```
<job-xml>hive-site.xml</job-xml>
```

in the job description, and have copied `hive-site.xml` to `HDFS` to the correct folder but to no avail. Additionally, I have double checked all URLs and everything is right.

I am running the `Oozie` job from command line. I have no idea where to start debugging or how to get a more detailed error. Following are screenshots:
[image: Oozie Error]
`Oozie` Error

[image: Hive job success]
Underlying `Hive` job indicates successful completion.

I do not see the final result as hive table as I am supposed to see.

Following is the log output of the Map task:

```
<<< Invocation of Hive command completed <<<

 Hadoop Job IDs executed by Hive: 

Intercepting System.exit(12)

<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [12]

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully

Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/oozie-oozi/0000005-160711211729704-oozie-oozi-W/define_congress_table--hive/action-data.seq
2016-07-12 05:30:57,817 INFO  [main] zlib.ZlibFactory (ZlibFactory.java:<clinit>(49)) - Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
2016-07-12 05:30:57,818 INFO  [main] compress.CodecPool (CodecPool.java:getCompressor(153)) - Got brand-new compressor [.deflate]

Oozie Launcher ends
2016-07-12 05:30:57,836 INFO  [main] mapred.Task (Task.java:done(1038)) - Task:attempt_1468271868299_0037_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
2016-07-12 05:30:57,878 INFO  [main] mapred.Task (Task.java:commit(1199)) - Task attempt_1468271868299_0037_m_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
2016-07-12 05:30:57,887 INFO  [main] output.FileOutputCommitter (FileOutputCommitter.java:commitTask(582)) - Saved output of task 'attempt_1468271868299_0037_m_000000_0' to hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/oozie-oozi/0000005-160711211729704-oozie-oozi-W/define_congress_table--hive/output/_temporary/1/task_1468271868299_0037_m_000000
2016-07-12 05:30:57,936 INFO  [main] mapred.Task (Task.java:sendDone(1158)) - Task 'attempt_1468271868299_0037_m_000000_0' done.
Log Type: syslog 
Log Upload Time: Tue Jul 12 05:31:05 +0000 2016 
Log Length: 2781 
2016-07-12 05:30:48,083 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-maptask.properties,hadoop-metrics2.properties
2016-07-12 05:30:48,151 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2016-07-12 05:30:48,152 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system started
2016-07-12 05:30:48,163 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Executing with tokens:
2016-07-12 05:30:48,163 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Kind: mapreduce.job, Service: job_1468271868299_0037, Ident: (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.token.JobTokenIdentifier@1fbe7534)
2016-07-12 05:30:48,212 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Kind: RM_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: 10.0.2.15:8050, Ident: (owner=root, renewer=oozie mr token, realUser=oozie, issueDate=1468301434802, maxDate=1468906234802, sequenceNumber=22, masterKeyId=90)
2016-07-12 05:30:48,257 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Sleeping for 0ms before retrying again. Got null now.
2016-07-12 05:30:48,496 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: mapreduce.cluster.local.dir for child: /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1468271868299_0037
2016-07-12 05:30:48,955 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2016-07-12 05:30:49,414 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
2016-07-12 05:30:49,414 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
2016-07-12 05:30:49,423 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2016-07-12 05:30:49,475 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: Unexpected: procfs stat file is not in the expected format for process with pid 4558
2016-07-12 05:30:49,647 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Processing split: org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.OozieLauncherInputFormat$EmptySplit@1f16b6e6
2016-07-12 05:30:49,654 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 0
2016-07-12 05:30:49,700 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.id
2016-07-12 05:30:50,069 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
2016-07-12 05:30:50,253 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.2.15:8050
```

Comment: Did you check the log of the MR job? Because the jobs launched by the Oozie are marked as Successful even in case of failure, to prevent retrying them by MR. Check the `stdout` and `stderr` logs in the MR job.

Comment: Yes I am looking at them, they say success for the `oozie` job in question. To make sure that I am looking at the right logs, I have looked at `MapReduce` application's local logs from the UI at `sandbox.hortonworks.com:19888/jobhistory` and it takes to `sandbox.hortonworks.com:8042/logs/hadoop-mapreduce.jobsummary.log`

Comment: You need to click on the map which is successful and then check the logs. Summary page is not enough.

Comment: Added logs to question

Comment: You need to check and provide the logs from `stderr`. The above logs have no useful information to debug the issue/

Comment: How can I access those?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117046/discussion-between-younghobbit-and-speedbirdnine).

Answer (score 0):

Changing action to hive2 from hive1 has fixed the same issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

To find the error check:

1. Check the "Child Job URLs" check each child job.
2. Check `stdout` and `stderr`

Sometime the error is in the child job and you will need to do some drill down on every one of them.

Comment: This does not answer anything to the OP. How to check logs and stuff is already provided in the comments. You should be using comment for such things.